# how do you infinitely call a function after its done executing (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

so if i make a function

```
function start(callback) {
  //do stuff
  callback()
}
```

how do I repeat this function over and over again?

Comment: use a while loop.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Infinitely running code is generally not something you want to try to do.

Comment: You want to repeat the `start()` function, right? Is it an asynchronous function? Using callback suggests that, though the way you call `callback()` doesn't comply (but that may be just the notation trying to by succinct). Do you mean for the next call to come after/in the callback?

Comment: You should add some information about what you are trying to do. If you need this for a custom gameLoop requestAnimationFrame may be what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could doing it via a `interval`. In this example, the function get's executed every 100 milliseconds.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  console.log("Stuff");
}, 100);
```

---

Or you call it once and let it call itself. (Didn't make it executable, the site would crash.)

```
function doStuff() {
  console.log("Stuff");
  doStuff();
}
```

---

A while loop could do it too. (Here too.)

```
function doStuff() {
  console.log("Stuff");
}

while (true) {
  doStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`while` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) with `true` as condition part.

```
function start(callback) {
    //do stuff
    while (true) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward wrapper:

```
function wrapper() {
  start(wrapper);
}

wrapper();
```

But there is a catch - if your start function does not break the callstack (has any IO), then this approach will eventually overflow the callstack.

The safer one:

```
function wrapper() {
  setTimeout(() =>{start(wrapper)}, 0);
}

wrapper();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SetInterval also but Nina Scholz answer is way better. Example of SetInterval:

```
setInterval(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < positionList.length; i++) {
            if (i != 19)
                if (posList[19].left == posList[i].left && posList[19].top == posList[i].top) {

                    window.location.reload();
                }
        }
    }, 200)
```

Call this function in every 200 miliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(
   function(){ 
     alert("Hello"); 
   },2000
);
```

Use setInterval method which will callback your function every 2 seconds